# How to remove a range in list depending on a condition in dart?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, range

I made a list to separate to different lists of integers for a flutter project.
Now I want to remove all integers after the last null value. How can I do that ?

```
void main() {
  List<int> v =[];
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
      v.add(1);
    }
    v.add(null);
  }
  for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
    print(v[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the index of the last occurrence of `null` in the list and make a `sublist` starting from 0 to that index (+1 is used to include the last null value in the sublist):

```
  List<int> v2 = v.sublist(0, v.lastIndexOf(null) + 1);
  for(int i=0; i<v2.length; i++){
    print(v2[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to remove ranger data from list then you can use **removeWhere** , using this method you can remove ranger data based in condition

```
void main() {
List<int> v =[];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
   v.add(1);
  }
  v.add(null);
  v.removeWhere((x) => x is int);
 }
 for(int i=0; i<v.length; i++){
  print(v[i]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply do that by, taking another list and storing the reverse of the list v in the new list. Then find the index of the first null in the new list.
Then the index of the final null will be,
Let the index of the null value came out to be n,
then the value of the last null value in the list v will be,
**v.length - n + 1**
for example,

```
 rev = v.reversed;
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < rev.length; i++) {
                  if (rev[i] == null) {
                    break;
                  }
                }
```

Then the index will be v.length - i + 1. Now, just use `sublist` function in Dart.

Comment: You don't need to reverse the list and use a foor loop. Check my answer. Also, if it was a QA you should've posted it as QA!